# UILocalNotification not firing when the app is in working mode

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, foreground

There are quite a few questions on why local notification is not firing properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988986/uilocalnotification-not-firing) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974512/uilocalnotification-isnt-working-at-all),also there are several questions on why local notification is not firing when the application is in background state which I have also gone through [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313641/ios-uilocalnotification-not-being-displayed-while-app-in-background).

But to my surprise I haven't found any notification post related to foreground state or in active state,i.e. in my app I am facing this strange issue,i.e. local notification fires when the app enters background mode and it doesn't fire when the app is in active state or in foreground mode,to my surprise again,even after fire date set for notification is expired,immediately after entering background,the notification fires.

**EDIT**

Also another issue I am facing is the alert is not firing,i.e. the alert action we write in didReceive local notification method,here is the implementation code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:addViewController.textField.text];
    [self.addViewController showReminder:reminderText];
}
```

And here is that showReminder method which is present in another controller i.e.:

```
//Notification alert
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];

    UIImage *image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon@2x.png"];
    [imageView setImage:image];

    [alertView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Sorry if this issue doesn't require a question or post in stackoverflow.

Any one please post your suggestions and any help is gladly appreciated!

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the application is active then you will not recieve any sound, badge or alert, however the application delegate `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` will be called

From [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers
>   the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound
>   is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is
>   called if the application delegate implements it. The
>   UILocalNotification instance is passed into this method, and the
>   delegate can check its properties or access any custom data from the
>   userInfo dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr.Omar.But in my application,say if the user is using the application,if he/she is not intimated regarding the reminder,there is no meaning in building my application :(

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya application:didReceiveLocalNotification is called, why not show an alert there if you want an alert?

Comment: @janusfidel Actually alert is not being displayed,that's another issue I have on the other side of the coin :(

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya if that is another issue, you might want to edit your question and post the code when you show UIAlertView :)

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith That is not getting called and that's the reason why alert is not being displayed

Comment: @Eshwar Chaitanya, Then you may have missed to initialize *self.addViewController*. Make sure that it is not nil.

Comment: as @EmptyStack said, your addViewController is most likely nil

Comment: @EmptyStack Yeah let me check it and get back to you

Comment: Yeah it is working,but the thing is it is throwing a small warning "Wait fences failed to receive reply"

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya, [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580724/491980) may help you.

Comment: @EmptyStack But the answer given there is what I am already fond of,and there is no issue with the alert view,but the problem is wait fences still :)

Comment: Instead of[self.addViewController showReminder:reminderText]; try the following [self.addViewController performSelector:@selector(showReminder) withObject:reminderText afterDelay:1];,  do you still get the warning?

Comment: @Eshwar Chaitanya, The answer in the post in the above link indirectly tells what Omar Abdelhafith has said above. Anyway you have got your problem fixed. Cheers!