# location based `local Notification` works in the `background` but not in the `foreground`

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, cllocation, region, background-foreground

Notification should activate whenever the location is near, but it only works in the background. Even though the triggering event happens in both the foreground and background.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

//implement local notification:
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

if (notification == nil)
    return;
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.alertBody = [selectedTask discription];
notification.alertAction = [selectedTask taskName];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
localNotification = nil;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220237/uilocalnotification-not-firing-when-the-app-is-in-working-mode

Comment: right so how do you fix it?

Comment: Fix what exactly? application:didReceiveLocalNotification is fired so you need to handle your action from there if you are wanting to display something to the user.

Comment: Elaborate on how to display a notification would fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside your didReceiveLocalNotification method you can display an alert to the user since notifications are not handled if the app is in the foreground.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle: @"Something"
        message: @"Something else you want to tell the user"
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```